Как корректно вывести массив numpy darray в QLabel.pixmap (PySide6)?
Вопрос на первый взгляд максимально простой, однако вызвал определенного рода сложности. При попытке задать pixmap в QLabel, выводится что-то из разряда белого шума.
Сам код выглядит следующим образом:
ds=dcmread(filepath)
temp=QImage(ds.pixel_array,ds.Rows,ds.Columns,ds.Rows,QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_GRAYSCALE8)
Img_Label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(temp))


В то же время, если без конвертации просто вывести pixel_array в matplotlib, то все выводится корректно:

Собственно, вопрос - в чем я ошибаюсь?

Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему

@S.Nick вопрос уже решился на англоязычном форуме.
